# Observe other application quit or sudden termination in cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, macos, termination

I need to create wrapper around application, so I created little cocoa app that opens application with `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:…]`, can I register some event when that application quits or terminates (I certainly need to get event if app is finished good or bad way). I know that I can ask if such application is running every second, but I hope that there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Technical Note TN2050](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050) "Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling"

Particularly the NSWorkspace notifications `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification` and `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification`